# Get number of weeks for a given ISO 8601 calendar year

Tags: swift, date, calendar, nsdate, iso8601

I need to make a function for calculating the number of weeks of a given year in Swift according to the ISO-week-system (ISO8601). I need the number as an Int. First I figured I need to make an `NSDate` for December 31st and just ask what week that's in. Then I realized that sometimes December 31st is in week 1 of the following year (for example, December 31st 2014).

Does anybody know of a way to do this?

I tried:

```
var calendarr = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)!
var monday = "01-01-2005"

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
var datumet = dateFormatter.date(from: monday)
var weekRange = calendarr.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .year, for: datumet!)
var weeksCount = weekRange.length

print("this many weeks", weeksCount)
```

However, it gives me 53 weeks no matter what year I put in. As a reference, 2004 had 53 weeks and 2005 had 52 weeks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple formula to determine the number of weeks in a year
of the ISO calendar can be found in [Long and Short ISO Calendar Years](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/calendar/isocalendar_text3.htm):

> An ISO calendar year y is long (contains 53 weeks) if:
>
> - p(y) modulo 7 = 4
>   or if:
> - p(y–1) modulo 7 = 3
>   with:
> - p(y) = y + floor(y/4) – floor(y/100) + floor(y/400)

Note that the version in [Wikipedia: Weeks per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year) seems
to have a small error, "if p(year) = 5" should be "if p(year) = 4".

This is an implementation in Swift:

```
func weeks(in year: Int) -> Int {
    func p(_ year: Int) -> Int {
        return (year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400) % 7
    }
    return (p(year) == 4 || p(year-1) == 3) ? 53 : 52
}
```

Test:

```
print(weeks(in: 2015)) // 53
print(weeks(in: 2016)) // 52

let longYears = (2000...2100).filter({ weeks(in: $0) == 53 })
print(longYears)
// [2004, 2009, 2015, 2020, 2026, 2032, 2037, 2043, 2048, 2054, 2060, 2065, 2071, 2076, 2082, 2088, 2093, 2099]
```

which coincides with the list given in the Wikipedia article.

---

## Update

Regarding the code block that you added to your question: Your code is almost correct.

As [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042) already said in a comment, it should be

```
let weekRange = calendarr.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: datumet!)
```

In addition, January 1st may fall into the *previous* ISO year
(e.g. for the year 2016). Choosing any day between January 4 and December 28 in the given year would solve that problem.

With some further simplifications that gives the following
method (based on [Kevin Sabbe's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490385/1187415)):

```
func weeks(in year: Int) -> Int {
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    let date = DateComponents(calendar: cal, year: year, month: 2, day: 1).date!
    let weeksRange = cal.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: date)!
    return weeksRange.count
}
```

which produces the same results as the function above.

## Addendum

As [@Olex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838279) suggested in a comment, this is even better (“no magic number '2' and stays in the paradigm of 'week-of-year' calculations”):

```
func weeks(in year: Int) -> Int {
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    let date = DateComponents(calendar: cal, weekday: 1, weekOfYear: 1, yearForWeekOfYear: year).date!
    let weeksRange = cal.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: date)!
    return weeksRange.count
}
```

Comment: imo `DateComponents(calendar: cal, weekday: 1, weekOfYear: 1, yearForWeekOfYear: year)` is better (no magic number '2' and stays in the paradigm of 'week-of-year' calculations)

Comment: @Olex: Yes, I agree. I have added it to the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Work for Swift 3:

```
let weekRange = NSCalendar.current.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: Date())

print("\(weekRange?.count)")
```

You have to specify the year in the Date() and it will give you the number of weeks for the entire year.

I hope it helps!

Comment: For the *ISO-week-system* you need the `ISO8601` calendar of `NSCalendar` and the unit `.yearForWeekOfYear`

Comment: Vadian, could you please look at the code I added in my question and show me where .yearForWeekOfYear should be. I tried both in the "of:" slot and the "in:" slot of the weekRange-line

Comment: @KlasZetterlund: It should be `in: .yearForWeekOfYear`. In addition, you must not choose Jan 1st as the date because that may fall into the previous ISO year. With `01-02-yyyy` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

extension Date {
    
    var lastDayOfMonth: Date {
        return set(dayOfMonth: Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!.count)
    }
    
    func set(dayOfMonth: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: self)
        components.day = dayOfMonth
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }
    
    func set(month: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: self)
        components.month = month
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }
    
    var weekNumber: Int {
        return Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.component(.weekOfYear, from: self)
    }
    
    var numberOfWeeksInYear: Int {
        let weekNumber = set(month: 12).lastDayOfMonth.weekNumber
        return weekNumber == 1 ? 52 : weekNumber
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that you want is the following:

```swift
func numberOfWeeksInYear(_ year: Int) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: 1, day: 4)
    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    let range = calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: date)!
    return range.count
}
```

You want to create a date which corresponds to the 4th of January because it's possible for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd of January to be part of the last week of the previous year according to the ISO8601 calendar.<sup>1</sup> 2021 is an example of this.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is because weeks start on Mondays according to the ISO8601 calendar and the first four days of the year must all fall in the same Monday-to-Sunday week for that week to be considered part of that year.</sup>