# Is there a way to get the exact number of weeks in a given year?

Tags: swift, date

Is there a way to get the exact number of weeks in a given year in Swift (e.g. 52 or 53)?

In my region (week starts with Monday, minimum 4 days in first week), we get 52 weeks in some years (e.g. 2019, 2021-2025) and 53 weeks in others (e.g. 2020, 2026).

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489006/get-number-of-weeks-for-a-given-iso-8601-calendar-year

Comment: Please clarify your question. A year with 365 days has 52.1428571 weeks and a year with 366 days has 52.2857143 weeks. So what is your basis for getting 52 or 53?

Comment: Hi, in my region (week starts with Monday, min 4 days in first week) we get 52 weeks (e.g. 2019, 2021-2025) or 53 weeks (e.g. 2020, 2026). That's my basic for the background of my question.

Comment: @HangarRash What the OP is asking for is the number of weeks in a year according to the ISO-8601 definition of weeks. That is the first week of a year is the one that has at least 4 days in the new year (by that definition, sometimes the last few days of a year are counted as week 1 in the new year, and sometimes the first few days of a new year are counted as week 53 or 52 of the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of weeks by combining `Calendar` and `DateComponents` like this:

```
let year = 2023
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year)
let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
let range = calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .year, for: date)!

let numberOfWeeks = range.count
```

Comment: This can only work reliably if you create an ISO8601 calendar and get the range of `.weekOfYear` in `.yearForWeekOfYear`.

Comment: With the .yearForWeekOfYear - change and the conditions for my region: 
(var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian) / calendar.firstWeekday = 2 / calendar.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 4)
the code seems to work properly. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: No, not `gregorian`, a week based calendar is `iso8601`

Comment: Ooops! Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified in your question that you want to perform the calculation for a calendar-system in which weeks start on Mondays and the first four days of the year must all fall in the same Monday-to-Sunday week for that week to be considered part of that year. That is the ISO8601 calendar.<sup>1</sup>

With those preconditions in place, the precise question that you need to ask of the system is: How many weeks are there in a given year for the date which corresponds to the 4th of January of that year according to the ISO8601 calendar? The function that will return you the answer to this question is the following:

```
func numberOfWeeksInYear(_ year: Int) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: 1, day: 4)
    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    let range = calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .yearForWeekOfYear, for: date)!
    return range.count
}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>You can verify this by creating a `Calendar` instance with `Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)` and inspecting its [firstWeekday](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293656-firstweekday) and [minimumDaysInFirstWeek](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293094-minimumdaysinfirstweek) properties. You'll see that they return `2` and `4` respectively. If you create a `Calendar` instance with `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` on the other hand you'll see that its [firstWeekday](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293656-firstweekday) and [minimumDaysInFirstWeek](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293094-minimumdaysinfirstweek) properties both return `1`.</sup>